# Azure Postgres Single server version upgrade

Tags: postgresql, azure-postgresql

Azure Postgres Single server version is 11. Is it possible to upgrade it to 13+ version using dump and restore as mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/how-to-upgrade-using-dump-and-restore

It should still remain Single Server.

Comment: The documentation tells you that this is possible, what happend when you tried?

Comment: Your question is no entirely clear. A SQL Dump and Restore from 11 to 13 will work in almost all scenarios. However, you mention that it should still remain a Single Sever, and the max version you can get on Single Server is 11.x If you want to upgrade to 13.x you will need to first create a new server using Flexible Server product (different product) and then do dump and restore to that machine. There is no 'push the button' upgrade between major versions of Postgres on Azure. And Single Server with version 10 will be decommissioned Nov 2022, and version 11 around the same time 2023.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The document you shared is Microsoft's official and therefore there is no doubt that you can upgrade it to any higher version using dump and restore.

Just take care of the below mentioned points:

You can upgrade your PostgreSQL server deployed in Azure Database for PostgreSQL by migrating your databases to a higher major version server using following methods.

- Offline method using PostgreSQL `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` which **incurs downtime for migrating the data**.
- Online method using Database Migration Service (DMS). This method provides a **reduced downtime migration** and **keeps the target database in-sync** with the source and you can choose when to cut-over. However, there are few prerequisites and restrictions to be addressed for using DMS.

The following table provides some recommendations based on database sizes and scenarios.

[image]

Choose the right approach based on your database configuration and it should be done without any issue.

To upgrade using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`, you can refer [Migrate your PostgreSQL database by using dump and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-migrate-using-dump-and-restore).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.
In the document, prerequisites states:

> A source PostgreSQL database server running a lower version of the
> engine that you want to upgrade. A target PostgreSQL database server
> with the desired major version Azure Database for PostgreSQL server -
> Single Server or Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server.

The question asks about upgrading target.